# insert an URL in mysql database using php script with GET method

Tags: php, mysql

http://192.168.1.7/cars_store/insert_annoce.php?urlFace=firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/carsstore-1c8c5.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fimage%3A60Sat+Dec+24+10%3A39%3A10+EST+2016?alt=media&token=908e383e-1901-4c04-855d-d6c7280b40a1

```
   $urlFace=$_GET['urlFace'];
   echo $urlFace;
```

and this is the result of the script:
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/carsstore-1c8c5.appspot.com/o/photos/image:60Sat Dec 24 10:39:10 EST 2016?alt=media

I always get the url missing the last part (after '&token=' ) method

Comment: Please show the full code ..

Comment: there is no `urlFace` in that url, yet alone any mysql so why the tag?

Comment: this question is way too unclear.

Comment: you may have left the question or not responding to comments. You've been given an answer below, ask them. I have left this question.

Comment: I edit it , is it cleat ?

Comment: It's less clear now, but I think I understand what you're tyring to say.  Read my answer below.  It solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the URL as a GET parameter within another URL, you'll have to somehow escape it so that it is distinguishable from the url that contains it.

an easy solution would be to use POST, where the data doesn't get sent as part of the URL, and therefore doesn't have this problem.

Otherwise, you'll have to encode your URI within a URI: http://php.net/rawurlencode

Comment: Given the (very little code/information) given, this may have best been a comment. You may be in for a very long haul.

Comment: More likely, the question will just be abandoned.  doesn't look like the OP is  at the stackoverflow level quite yet.

Comment: The OP seems to have come back and their edit, makes it even more unclear. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page

Eg:

```
$my_url = "http://192.168.1.7/cars_store/insert_annoce.php?
urlFace=".urlencode("firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/carsstore-
1c8c5.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fimage%3A60Sat+Dec+24+10%3A39%3A10+EST+2016?
alt=media&token=908e383e-1901-4c04-855d-d6c7280b40a1");
```

You can use `$my_url` in `<a> tags` , `form actions` etc.

Then `$_GET[urlFace]` in `annoce.php` will give the full url you needed